# Which is faster, .on() or .click()?

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

If I have a table with links to delete a record, which is the best way to wire up the click event? Do these evaluate the same under the hood?

```
$("#table").on("click", ".delete", function(){
   //do stuff
});
```

or

```
$("#table .delete").click(function(){
   //do stuff
});
```

Comment: For assigning, `on` will be faster as `click` calls `on` internally. But I really doubt it has influence on your application's overall performance. Have a look at the source code for these kind of questions: https://github.com/jquery/jquery What's more important here is that these calls are not equivalent. The first only attaches one event handler and makes use of event delegation, whereas the second one attaches an event handler to ever `.delete` inside `#table`.

Comment: either one is fine.  `on` would be used if the contents of `#table` are changed, say a reload from ajax.

Comment: If you add extra delete items after calling these functions only the first one will work. Because here the clicks go to the table which then looks for delete children. In the second the clicks only go to delete items that existed when the function was called.

Comment: It's like asking what is faster `int` or `string` in `C#` each type has it's uses...

Comment: @gdoron ... no... it's not like that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they don't.

In the way you are using them...

`.on()` **The way you are using it (delegation)**, will save you cycles at attachment as well as memory, because it doesn't actually attach the events in that moment, as it provides a dynamic element where the event is applied to future elements as well.

`.click()` will save you cycles at execution, as it explicitly attaches an event to every matching element at that moment in time, but in reality, this would be the last place I'd look for a bottleneck.

[Read some testing with event delegation here...](http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck)

[Performance testing of attaching event handlers...](http://jsperf.com/jquery-event-delegation/7)

Comment: Time at execution cannot make any noticeable difference because any time difference is negligible compared with the speed of a user pressing click.

Comment: sure, I stated as much in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's like asking what is faster `int` or `string` in `C#`. Each type has it's uses...
It's not about which is faster, it's about what to use when.

`on` allows you to attach event to dynamically added elements while `click` does not.

if you don't have "dynamically added elements" use click, otherwise use `on`.

Comment: +1 just for saying "It's not about which is faster, it's about what to use when."

Comment: -1 one for comparing this to "int vs string" .on and .click can be massively different and I don't think its a bad question considering that .on replaced .delegate and that replace .live  and I think anyone who used .live a lot know how slow that was.

however +2 for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

`click` is faster that `on` because it attaches the event directly on the element where as `on` is attaching the event on `#table` and looking for `.delete` element to trigger the event so there is some code execution involved before the `click` event is triggered.

The difference is negligible though you will not see any difference.

If you use `on` the only one event handler is enough to take care of any number of `.delete` elements inside the `#table` where as `click` will be attached to each of the `.delete` elements so `on` better in terms of memory utilization.

Comment: faster when attaching the event? or when firing it?

Comment: I mean while triggering the event.

Comment: Where does it a say that `on` is faster than `click` while firing the event?

Answer (score 1):

In this particular scenario, the `.click(...)` will (likely) be slower, because it will need to iterate through each row and each cell that matches the selector, and attach the handler function to each one.  The `on(...)`, in this particular case, is likely to be faster, because it attaches the handler to the table, not to each element that has the `.delete` class.

That being said, you need to consider a few things when choosing between these two:

1. How complex is your selector?  If you are doing `$('#rootItem').on('click', '.foo .bar.baz .bum', function() { /* do stuff*/ })`, this will be inherently slower than `$('#rootItem').on('click', '.foo', function() { /* do stuff*/ })` because the selector is more complex in the former case.  In this kind of scenario, it might make more sense to pay the price on attachment and use `click(...)` to save the run-time cost of evaluating every click within `#rootItem` to see if it matches the selector `'.foo .bar.baz .bum'`.  A simple single-class selector like you have (`'.delete'`) will perform just fine.
2. Will the contents be changing dynamically?  If so, you'll be responsible for calling `click(...)` on each dynamically-added item.  The `on(...)` function can handle this a little better, as long as your "outside" selector (`'#table'` in this case) doesn't point at elements that will be dynamically added.  Replace `'#table'` with `'.table'`, and dynamically add a new table with class `table`, and the newly-added table won't have event handlers attached to it from your initial call to `on(...)`.