# Which method of binding a javascript event with jquery's on is more performant?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, events

Let's say you have a web page with forms, and you want to trigger a handler whenever one of those forms is submitted, or whenever a form that is added to the page at a later point in time is submitted. Which method is better:

```
$('form').on('submit', handler);
```

or

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', handler);
```

Comment: document will always work, but it's generally better to attach the handler to an element as close as possible to where the event will occur.

Comment: It reminded me [my old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9164854/601179).

Comment: simple rule of thumb for `on()`... anything before the event name has to exist when code is run, otherwise have to delegate further up tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to apply to forms you will add to your page later dynamically, the latter is the only version that will work at all.

(Honestly, unless your page has thousands of forms, the performance difference shouldn't matter much anyway)

Answer (score 0):

It's not which is better, it's which is more suitable for your needs, both of the methods are good and have their usage.

The first only listens to submits that occur inside of forms, the latter listens to all submits, wait for them to bubble to the `document`, and then fire the `handler` callback.

Note that with `onsubmit`, it doesn't have so much difference, as with `mousemove` or `click` which can occur on every place in the `<body>`, submit only happens in `<forms>`, but it bubbles all the way to the document.

Comment: Will the first be triggered if a form added in the future is submitted?